# How to freeze columns in Vuestic UI data table (vue3)

Tags: vuejs3, vuestic

I am using Vuestic UI with Vue3. I am using the [data table component](https://vuestic.dev/en/ui-elements/data-table). I would like to accomplish [this effect](https://hc200ok.github.io/vue3-easy-data-table-doc/features/fixed-column.html) (reference from a different component) of freezing the first two columns of the table.

Is it possible with the Vuestic data table component and, if so, how can it be achieved?

Comment: *"Freezing"* a column table is not a consecrated term. What exactly do you mean by it? Do you mean applying a fixed width in pixels which should be respected above all else, regardless of the table's total width? From a quick glance at the available documentation, it looks like [column styling](https://vuestic.dev/en/ui-elements/data-table#column-styling) is your best option. Have you tried *anything* so far? Please read [ask] and [How much research effort is expected of StackOverflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/1891677).

Comment: I suggest creating a *runnable* [mcve] using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/docs/learn/getting-started/your-first-sandbox#import-local-projects-via-cli) or similar, where potential solutions could be tested. Without a runnable example your chances of getting a useful answer are significantly lower (as the effort required to test a potential solution is higher).

Comment: I have added the [link](https://hc200ok.github.io/vue3-easy-data-table-doc/features/fixed-column.html) with the exact effect (and code to produce it) that I was looking for. The minimal reproducible example is a good suggestion though, even though the first link has those. The question was indeed broad, I was expecting someone from the community to detect the tags and say either: "we don't support" (which is the case) or "we do support in a nightly version, do this".

Comment: It's rare for package maintainers/authors to answer [SO] questions or follow their package's tag (when it exists on StackOverflow). On average, you'll get a much quicker response by opening an issue on the repo.

Answer (score 1):

They have answered me in their [github repository](https://github.com/epicmaxco/vuestic-ui/discussions/3097): they do not support that yet for data tables, but they suggest [ag-grid](https://vuestic.dev/en/extensions/ag-grid) for this use case.